# Some of my friends can't see my friends publications (restricted list?)

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I remember that at some point I added a few friends to a "restricted list". Things seem to have changed now and I cannot seem to find a way to edit these settings.

Whenever I post something, next to the post it says "Shared with: your friends".

However, when a friend, say Bob, tags me and the post appears on my profile, it says:

> This is Bob's post. It's been shared with: Bob's friends, and some of Xavier's friends

(Xavier is me). When I drill down, it says:

> Who can see this?
>   On your timeline: Friends; Except: X, Y and Z
>   Everywhere else: Bob's friends and some of Xavier's friends

Now I wonder what I can change so that X, Y and Z can see these posts.
These people seem to only be added to normal friend lists.
Also, my "Restricted" friend list seem to be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what you have set in your [Timeline and Tagging Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=timeline). There is a setting there labeled "Who can see posts you've been tagged in on your timeline?" You can set both a "Share this with" and "Don't share this with" list. Payouts may have added X, Y and Z in there.

Comment: That was it, thanks! Somehow I had missed those options.

Comment: Glad you're sorted now. Always good to get feedback that a problem is solved :-)